# Regular expression for numeric field with less than 13 digits

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to know how to write a regular expression for validation of numeric field with less than 13 digits. No decimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl compatible:  `^[0-9]{1-12}$`.  One to twelve of the character class '0' through '9', with nothing before or after.

Comment: I have tried `[RegularExpression("^[0-9]{1-12}$")]`, all numbers I have tried so far came out invalid. What might be wrong?